# IllegalStateException:Fragment already active

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a passed data from `FragmentActivity` to multiple fragments like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("userid", logindata);
firstfragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

From fragment Activity to secong fragment i have pass data like this.

```
secondfragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

when i click first fragment it's working next click second fragment it's also working fine but again click first fragment the `illegal state exception Fragment already active` exception will be occur. How to reslove this problem please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `setArguments` only called before the fragment has been attached to its activity otherwise through `Fragment already active` Exception. so call `setArguments` to should need to remove fragment is already present and use replace to add fragment again

Comment: see i am using like this firstfragment.setArguments(bundle);
    transactn = mngr.beginTransaction();
    transactn.replace(R.id.content_frag, firstfragment).addToBackStack("firstfragment").commit();

Comment: have you removed firstfragment before calling replace method?

Comment: no. i'm not remove any fragment before calling the replace method.

Comment: see my  answer probably help

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK if i remove firstfragment before calling the replace method same issue will be occur.

Answer (score 2):

```
illegal state exception Fragment already active
```

`setArguments` only called before the fragment has been attached to its activity otherwise through Fragment already active Exception. so call `setArguments` to should need to remove fragment is already present and use replace to add fragment again.

Remove fragment before adding new :

```
Fragment fragment = 
               getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("firstfragment");
if(fragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                               .remove(fragment).commit();
```

Now add new fragment :

```
 firstfragment.setArguments(bundle); 
 transactn = mngr.beginTransaction(); 
 transactn.replace(R.id.content_frag,firstfragment).
                    addToBackStack("firstfragment").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    createFragment(new YourFragment());

    private void createFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_app, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: You did not set the Arguments. We get the exception when we do setArguments(). This does not help.